# preg_match php error - No ending delimiter '^' found

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php regular expressions No ending delimiter ‘^’ found in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634993/php-regular-expressions-no-ending-delimiter-found-in)

The code is as follows:

```
if(preg_match($exp, $value)){
   return "";           
}
```

- the value of `$exp` is: `^[0-9]*$`
- the value of `$value` is: `7`

and the output gives :

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^' found in /...

Comment: Which was easy to find by searching your exact question title on the site. Please do that as well before actually asking the question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334591/why-does-this-regular-expression-result-in-preg-match-no-ending-delimite and the many others, your error is quite common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$exp` should be something like `/^[0-9]*$/` for it to work the way you intended. It is assuming `^` is your regex delimiter, because it is the first character - you'd want your first char to be something else. See [preg_match manual entry](http://php.net/preg_match) for details.